# Paste content from clipboard into rtfield inside a new section

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a big problem =)
I copy the hole body content of an email to the clipbard and need to paste this content in a richtextfield.

My problem is now, to paste this content from clipboard inside a section.

So i have to create a section in the current Richtextfield the user is into and paste the content from clipboard into this section.

I've tried it with diffrent methods but nothing works.
Maybe there's a solution with RTNavigators or ranges, but i have no idea.

Someone has a a possible solution for me?

thanks in advance

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim currField As String
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim style As NotesRichTextStyle
Dim color As NotesColorObject

Set uidoc = ws.Currentdocument
Set db = s.Currentdatabase
Dim DummyDoc As NotesDocument
Dim DummyRT As NotesRichTextItem

currField = uidoc.Currentfield

'Create DummyDoc
Set DummyDoc = db.CreateDocument 
Call DummyDoc.Createrichtextitem("dummy")
Set DummyRT = DummyDoc.Createrichtextitem("DummyRT")
Call DummyDoc.Save(True,True)

'Open DummyDoc in workspace
Dim dummyUIDoc As NotesUIDocument
Set dummyUIDoc = ws.Editdocument(True, DummyDoc,True)

'Paste copied content
Call dummyUIDoc.Gotofield("dummy")
Call dummyUIDoc.Paste()
Call dummyUIDoc.Refresh(True,False,True)
Call dummyUIDoc.Save()
Call dummyUIDoc.Close(True)

'Create Section
Dim secUIDoc As NotesUIDocument

Set style = s.CreateRichTextStyle
Set color = s.CreateColorObject

Call DummyRT.BeginSection("", style, color, True)
Call DummyRT.EndSection

Call DummyDoc.Save(True, False, False)
Set secUIDoc = ws.EditDocument(True, DummyDoc)
Call DummyDoc.Remove(True)

Call secUIDoc.Gotofield("DummyRT")
Call secUIDoc.Selectall()
Call secUIDoc.Copy()
Call secUIDoc.Close(true)

'Paste generated content
Call uidoc.Gotofield(currField) 
Call uidoc.Paste()  

Dim range As NotesRichTextRange 
Dim count As Integer 
Dim nav As NotesRichTextNavigator

Set rtitem = uidoc.Document.Getfirstitem(currField)

Set range = rtitem.CreateRange 
Set nav = rtitem.CreateNavigator
Call nav.FindFirstString("#PH#") 
Call range.SetBegin(nav) 
Call range.SetEnd(nav) 
Call range.Remove 
Call uidoc.Paste()
```

Second try

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim currField As String
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim style As NotesRichTextStyle
Dim color As NotesColorObject

Set uidoc = ws.Currentdocument
Set db = s.Currentdatabase
Dim DummyDoc As NotesDocument
Dim DummyRT As NotesRichTextItem

currField = uidoc.Currentfield

'Insert Section
Set DummyRT = uidoc.Document.Getfirstitem(currField)
Call DummyRT.Beginsection("",style,color,true)
Call DummyRT.Appendtext("Test")
Call DummyRT.Endsection()
Call uidoc.Reload()

Call uidoc.Gotofield(currField)

Call uidoc.Paste()
```

Comment: Please show us the code for the methods that you tried, and tell us what happened when you tried them.

Answer (score 0):

BreakingPar has code on accessing the windows clipboard: http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256CFA00581AB2

You seemed to have some questions about using RTNavigators, and I think that's the way to go. Hoping it will be of assistance to you, I'm including a button I have that using RTNavigators to add a table in. I've not used sections, but I this may help.

Cheers,
Brian

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim firstDoc As NotesDocument
Dim tableDoc As New NotesDocument(db)
Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Dim univID As String
Set firstDoc = uidoc.Document
univID = firstDoc.UniversalID
Call uidoc.Close    
Msgbox univID
Dim tableItem As NotesRichTextItem  
Call tableDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form","Table Holder")   
Dim body As New NotesRichTextItem(tableDoc,"BuiltTable")
rowCount% = 4
columnCount% = 4
        'Order the table
Call body.AppendTable(rowCount%,columnCount%)
Dim rtnav As NotesRichTextNavigator
Set rtnav = body.CreateNavigator
Call rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)

For iRow% = 1 To rowCount% Step 1
    For iColumn% = 1 To columnCount% Step 1
        Call body.BeginInsert(rtnav)
        Call body.AppendText("Row " & iRow% & ", Column " & iColumn%)
        Call body.EndInsert
        Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)
    Next
Next
Call tableDoc.Save(True, False) 
Set tableItem = tableDoc.GetFirstItem("BuiltTable")
'Call tableItem.CopyItemToDocument(doc,"TableTarget")
Call tableItem.CopyItemToDocument(firstDoc, "TableTarget")
Call firstDoc.Save(True,False)
Call ws.ViewRefresh
Call ws.EditDocument(True,firstDoc,False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between Call uidoc.Refresh (True) [to refresh the RT Fields] and the 3 parameters option of Call.uidoc.Refresh(True, True, True)?  The notes documentation only references the one parameter and I have some code erroring on this line.  Your post was one of the few references I have found. :-/

Comment: I think the three parameter uidoc.Refresh in the OP is an error. I'm unaware of a correct 3 parameter uidoc.Refresh

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you know the name of the origin field, you can use the code below to copy the RT field from one document to another. "NewLink" is the name of my origin field.

Cheers,
Brian

```
Dim thisDoc As NotesDocument
Dim thisRT As Variant
Dim newRT As Variant
Dim newDoc As NotesDocument
Set uiws = New NotesUIWorkspace
Set sess = New NotesSession
Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase
Set thisuidoc = uiws.CurrentDocument
Set thisDoc = thisuidoc.Document    
Set thisRT = thisDoc.GetFirstItem("NewLink")
Set newDoc = db.CreateDocument
newDoc.Form = "RT"
Call newDoc.Save(True,False)    
Set newRT =  New NotesRichTextItem(newdoc,"newRTfield")
Call thisuidoc.Close
Call newRT.AppendRTItem(thisRT)
Call newdoc.Save(True,False)    
Set newuidoc = uiws.EditDocument(True, newDoc)
```